# Need to delete item from array using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

so I have a reducer that is adding to array 
create reducer :

```
export default (itemsList = [], action) => {
    if (action.type === 'ADD_ITEM') {
        return [...itemsList, action.payload]
    }
    return itemList
}
```

deleting reducer (99% that something is wrong here, but I have no idea what ):

```
export default (itemList = [], action) => {
    if (action.type === 'DELETE_ITEM') {
        return [...itemList, itemList.filter(item => item !== action.payload)]
    }
    return itemList
};
```

action/index.js:

```
export const addItemToList = item => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_ITEM',
        payload: selectedItem
    }
};

export const deleteItemFromList = item => {
    return{
        type: 'DELETE_ITEM',
        payload: selectedItem
    }
};
```

let say I have 
itemList = [ 'abc', 'xyz', 'qwe' ]

and I want to use deleteItem('xyz') to delete 'xyz' from itemList

Comment: What happens when you `deleteItem('xyz')`?

Comment: problem is that still nothing is happening. it doesnt delete the value from array and still i dont know what to do ...

Comment: what are the elements of the array? is it a primitive or an object? if an object can you write out its structure and what is the value of the payload, meaning what property are you targeting?

Comment: I have a dropdown that user can select multiple options and the selected values are in array as a strings. Then im showing user the values that he picked with button that schould delete them when user click on it. Buton is working fine. I bind key to the button and when im using console.log(key) it shows right key, but when I want to delete it, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

While deleting you just need to return the filtered list and not use spread operator too.

```
export default (itemList = [], action) => {
    if (action.type === 'DELETE_AUTHOR') {
        return itemList.filter(item => item !== action.payload)
    }
    return listOfAuthorsSelected
};
```

Comment: Sadly im trying all the time and cant make it work at all

Answer (score 0):

[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array with given filter condition and not mutate the existing array. You don't have need to use `...itemList`(spread operator). Here you are actually adding a sub array each time.

Here is a simple running example

```js
var array1 = ["abc", "def" , "ghi"];

var array2 = [...array1, array1.filter((item) => {
return item !== "def"
})];

document.write(array2);


// correct way to filter
var array3 = ["abc", "def" , "ghi"];

var array4 = array3.filter((item) => {
return item !== "def"
});

document.write("<hr/>"+array4);
```